# Provider keeps data after logout

Tags: flutter

In my first screen, I consume data from Firebase and store it in provider.
This data will be used in another screen.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirestorePreviousPage.documentsListDescending().then((query) {
      final totalHisabProvider = Provider.of<TotalHisab>(context, listen: false);
      totalHisabProvider.addItemsFromSnapshot(query);

      final unpaidHisabProvider = Provider.of<UnpaidHisab>(context, listen: false);
      unpaidHisabProvider.addItems(query);

      final paidHisabProvider = Provider.of<PaidHisab>(context, listen: false);
      paidHisabProvider.addItems(query);
    });
  }
```

The documentsListAscending method:

```
  static Future<QuerySnapshot> documentsListDescending() async {
    final user = await CurrentUser.getCurrentUser();

    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection(user.uid)
        .orderBy('serverTimestamp', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();
  }
```

My logout method:

```
  static Future<void> logout(BuildContext context) async {

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      WelcomeScreen.routeName,
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
  }
```

Now when I do logout and login with a different user, this new user still has access to the data of the previous user. Now I think I understand this part. As long as the app is working, it will keep the data in the state management.

But why doesn't the retrieve the new data from Firebase?
Shouldn't this line update data with the new user ID:             `.collection(user.uid)`

I have an idea of how to solve this. Just clear the data in all the providers in the logout method. But that doesn't feel right. I need to understand why it isn't working first.

Comment: clear local instances and also assign values to null

Comment: First check if you are getting the updated data from firebase on your 2nd login. Than check if you are properly assigning it to your providers. Check properly, and you will learn something new for sure..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up clearing the providers manually:

```
  static Future<void> logout(BuildContext context) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

    // Clear all providers
    Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).clear();
    Provider.of<UnpaidHisab>(context, listen: false).clear();
    Provider.of<PaidHisab>(context, listen: false).clear();
    Provider.of<TotalHisab>(context, listen: false).clear();

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      WelcomeScreen.routeName,
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
  }
```

It works just fine as far I can tell.

Comment: I don't think this is the best approach. Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: Agreed, I don't like this solution either. But it's the only one I can come up with.